# Преобразование массивов в PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Как в PHP привести массивы такого вида:

```
$ar1 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);
```

к такому виду:

```
$values = array(
    array('Месяц', 'Магазин 1', 'Магазин 2'),
    array('1', 15, 25),
    array('2', 25, 45),
    array('3', 30, 50),
);
```

Comment: Циклом можно. Что у вас не получилось?

Comment: Почитайте про транспонирование матрицы — это как раз Ваш случай...

Comment: @Zhukov Roman а как циклом можно создавать матрицу?

Comment: если число исходных массивов всегда равно 3м (ну или известно и не велико), то [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php) самый удобный вариант. в противном случае цикл по массивам и элементам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавлю в копилку пару вариантов:

1) Использование функции [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)

```
$result = array_map(function($a,$b,$c){ return [$a,$b,$c]; }, $ar3,$ar1,$ar2);
```

2) Использование функции [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-column.php)

```
$data = [$ar3, $ar1, $ar2];
$result  = [
            array_column($data,0),
            array_column($data,1),
            array_column($data,2),
            array_column($data,3),
         ];
```

Comment: `array_map(function(...$list){ return $list; }, $ar3,$ar1,$ar2);`

Comment: Пора бы в php добавить `arrow functions` =)

Comment: @teran спасибо, ваш ответ в одну строчку работает!

Answer (score 2):

2 цикла:

```
function flip($arr) {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arr as $index => $list) {
        foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key][$index] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$ar1 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);

$values = flip([$ar3, $ar1, $ar2]);

var_dump($values);
```

[Демо](https://3v4l.org/7Eopi)

Comment: а в PHP >= 5.6 можно писать `function flip(...$arr)` и на вход давать просто `$values = flip($ar3, $ar1, $ar2);`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ar1 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);


$result=array();


//Считаем количество массивов доступных для объединения (тут будет количество + 1. Потом отнимем)
$num=1;
while (isset(${'ar'.$num})) {
    $num++;
}


//Считаем количество элементов в массиве (предполагается, что везде они равны!) В идеале тут нужно проверку перебором всех массивов. Сами допишите).
$cnt=count($ar1);


//Проверка, чтобы всё было ок. По сути данные наши - это матрица
if ($num!=$cnt) {
    exit('Err');
}


$num--; //Получаем точное количество исходных массивов


//Начинаем заполнять итоговый массив
for ($i=1; $i <= $num ; $i++) { 

    foreach (${'ar'.$i} as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key][]=$value;
    }

}


print_r($result);
```

На выходе будет

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Магазин 1
            [1] => Магазин 2
            [2] => Месяц
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [1] => 25
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 45
            [2] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 30
            [1] => 50
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

**Чтобы получилось так, что в начале месяц**, а потом магазин 1 и 2 (без лишних заморочек), рекомендую изменить и порядок нумерации исходных массивов. Если, например, всегда последним массивом месяц, то зная общее количество массивов, проще всего пересоздать переменные, поменяв порядок. Т.е. порядок и нумерация исходных массивов должна быть такая:

```
$ar1 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar3 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
```

Тогда получите результат, как вы указали (если это 100% критично). Если это нужно, тогда код вот такой

```
$ar1 = array('Магазин 1', 15, 25, 30);
$ar2 = array('Магазин 2', 25, 45, 50);
$ar3 = array('Месяц', 1, 2, 3);


$result=array();


//Считаем количество массивов доступных для объединения (тут будет количество + 1. Потом отнимем)
$num=1;
while (isset(${'ar'.$num})) {
    $num++;
}


//Считаем количество элементов в массиве (предполагается, что везде они равны!).
$cnt=count($ar1);


//Проверка, чтобы всё было ок. По сути данные наши - это матрица
if ($num!=$cnt) {
    exit('Err');
}


$num--; //Получаем точное количество исходных массивов


//Изменяем нумерацию и порядок исходных массивов
$new_arr1=${'ar'.$num};
for ($i=2; $i <= $num; $i++) { 
    $n=$i-1;
    ${'new_arr'.$i}=${'ar'.$n};
}


//Тут можно удалить старые исходные массивы


//Начинаем заполнять итоговый массив
for ($i=1; $i <= $num ; $i++) { 

    foreach (${'new_arr'.$i} as $key => $value) {
        $result[$key][]=$value;
    }

}

print_r($result);
```

Старался всё сделать максимально просто и последовательно, не закидывая в кучу.

P.S. " подскажите как можн**а** в PHP". Я думал, что когда есть проверка правописания на лету, то можно уже как-нибудь да грамотно писать. Не могу сам исправить.

Comment: Чего только не сделают, лишь бы в массив не заворачивать...

Comment: можна исправил:), спасибо, ваш код пока разбираю, обязательно сообщу что получилось. В любом случае спасибо (хоть этого и следует избегать по правилам сайта).